# JavaScript prototype inheritance and html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, prototypal-inheritance

I'm a Ruby developer who finally decided to learn JavaScript seriously. So I purchased some books and I started to dive in, but I got stuck quickly when I tried to understand prototypal inheritance...

One of the examples of the book is the following. 
Given a Shape which prototype has a draw method, and two child shapes: a Triangle and a Rectangle which prototype inherit from Shape;

- when I call the draw function on Triangle and Rectangle instances the method will draw them properly.
- when I add a second method to show their name, every instance will log it properly.

Everything was understandable perfectly until I added a third method to fill the shapes... And only the last one get filled. no matter which one I call. Why? Is there something special in canvas?

Here is the code of the exercise:

```js
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

function Shape() {
  this.points = [];
  this.init();
}

Shape.prototype = {
  constructor: Shape,
  init: function() {
    if (this.context === undefined) {
      Shape.prototype.context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    };
    if (this.name === undefined) {
      Shape.prototype.name = 'generic shape'
    }
  },
  draw: function() {
    var i, ctx = this.context;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,255)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.points[0].x, this.points[0].y);
    for (i = 1; i < this.points.length; i++) {
      ctx.lineTo(this.points[i].x, this.points[i].y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  },
  fill: function(color) {
    var ctx = this.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
  },
  say_name: function() {
    console.log('Hello my name is ' + this.name)
  }
};

function Triangle(a, b, c) {
  this.points = [a, b, c];
  this.name = 'Triangle'
  this.context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
}

function Rectangle(side_a, side_b) {
  var p = new Point(200, 200);
  this.points = [
    p,
    new Point(p.x + side_a, p.y), // top right
    new Point(p.x + side_a, p.y + side_b), // bottom right
    new Point(p.x, p.y + side_b) // bottom left
  ];
  this.name = 'Rectangle'
  this.context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
}

(function() {
  var s = new Shape();
  Triangle.prototype = s;
  Rectangle.prototype = s;
})();

function testTriangle() {
  var p1 = new Point(100, 100);
  var p2 = new Point(300, 100);
  var p3 = new Point(200, 0);
  return new Triangle(p1, p2, p3);
}

function testRectangle() {
  return new Rectangle(100, 100);
}

function make_me_crazy() {
  var t = testTriangle();
  var r = testRectangle();
  t.draw();
  r.draw();
  t.say_name();
  r.say_name();
  t.fill('red');
}
make_me_crazy();
```

```html
<canvas height='600' width='800' id='canvas' />
```

Thank you!

More details:

- Why the function `say_name` is working exactly I expect saying: 'I am a triangle' or 'I am a rectangle' and never 'I am a generic shape', but the `fill` function fills the rectangle despite I'm calling it on a triangle instance? As people rightly answered to flip the two draw functions calls, I would specify better the following. The problem is not about the color of a shape, but the *context* pointer. why only the last shape is filled? If I add more shapes before calling `fill` only the last one get filled. This means I'm doing something wrong referring to the canvas. I supposed it was "the place where I draw shapes" but it seems more like "the last active shape"
- How can I fix that code to make it working correctly filling the shape I want *whenever I want*? I mean. what if I want to have a function which receive an instance of a particular shape and fills it?
- Is there any way to access a the draws contained into a canvas?

Comment: Within your `make_me_crazy` function, switch your draw calls (draw the rectangle first, then the triangle). The result of that should tell you something about context!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I supposed the context to be the "shape I'm working on" but is not.. is... the canvas?
If I add a third shape, the fill method fills it. So I deduce the context is the last active shape, no matter which one calls the `fill` method.. but why? How can properly refer to a shape in any moment?

Answer (score 1):

The core of the problem is the context - your shapes are sharing the *single* context of the canvas, and therefore it is not straight-forward to flip back and forth between objects. Instead, think of your order-of-operations as handling a single shape at a time and only moving on to the next one when you are done with the former.

Note the order of calls in the `make_me_crazy` function:

```js
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  function Shape() {
    this.points = [];
    this.init();
  }

  Shape.prototype = {
    constructor: Shape,
    init: function(){
      if (this.context === undefined) {
        Shape.prototype.context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
      };
      if(this.name === undefined){
        Shape.prototype.name = 'generic shape'
      }
    },
    draw: function(){
      var i, ctx = this.context;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,255)';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.points[0].x, this.points[0].y);
      for (i = 1; i<this.points.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(this.points[i].x, this.points[i].y);
      }
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();
    },
    fill: function(color){
      var ctx = this.context;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fill();
    },
    say_name: function(){console.log('Hello my name is '+ this.name)}
  };

  function Triangle(a,b,c){
    this.points = [a, b, c];
    this.name = 'Triangle'
    this.context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  }

  function Rectangle(side_a, side_b){
    var p = new Point(200, 200);
    this.points = [
      p,
      new Point(p.x + side_a, p.y),// top right
      new Point(p.x + side_a, p.y + side_b), // bottom right
      new Point(p.x, p.y + side_b)// bottom left
    ];
    this.name = 'Rectangle'
    this.context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  }

  (function(){
    var s = new Shape();
    Triangle.prototype = s;
    Rectangle.prototype = s;
  })();

  function testTriangle(){
    var p1 = new Point(100, 100);
    var p2 = new Point(300, 100);
    var p3 = new Point(200, 0);
    return new Triangle(p1, p2, p3);
  }

  function testRectangle(){
    return new Rectangle(100, 100);
  }

  function make_me_crazy(){
    var t = testTriangle();
    t.say_name();
    t.draw();
    t.fill('red');
    
    var r = testRectangle();
    r.draw();
    r.say_name();
  }
  make_me_crazy();
```

```html
<canvas height='600' width='800' id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: Right too. I have made me to rethink to my questions to find a better way to express my doubt. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

About the points of your question.

For the first one: the key is this line of code

```
if(this.name === undefined){
    Shape.prototype.name = 'generic shape'
}
```

When you instantiate `Rectangle` and `Triangle`, both of them set `name`.
In the other hand, the `render` method is only available in the `Shape` prototype.

About the second point (and the third one):
Maybe are you painting the `Rectangle` over the `Triangle`. Try to switch the order of the `draw` calls to check it.

Comment: Render method? mmhh maybe that's the point, as I use the same canvas for all the shapes maybe I should "reset" the context to the shape I want to fill... but how?

Comment: And, no, the two shapes don't overlap. (and if I add other shapes the fill method always fills the last one)