# Canvas is displaying a single object instead of multiple

Tags: javascript, object, html5-canvas

I've created a script for a bouncing ball, and I wanted to try to add another ball to make it more interesting. But the code doesn't seem to work and add another ball as I'm trying to do. I want to use the same function to do that because its more compact and flexible.

```js
function startGame() {
    GameArea.start();
 Ball = new CircComp('red' , window.innerWidth/ 2 , window.innerHeight / 2.5 );
 Ball.yAngle = 10;
 Ball.xAngle = 10;
 Ball.radius = 20; 
 Ball1 = new CircComp('green' , window.innerWidth/ 2 , window.innerHeight / 2.5 );
 Ball1.yAngle = -10;
 Ball1.xAngle = -10;
 Ball1.radius = 20;
}
var GameArea = {
 canvas : canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
 start : function (){
  this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
 },
 clear : function() {
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}
function CircComp(color, x , y){
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 context = GameArea.ctx;
 this.update = function(){
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,2*Math.PI);
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
 }
 this.updateGameComp = function(){
  GameArea.clear();
  this.y += this.yAngle; 
  this.x += this.xAngle;
  if(this.x + this.radius > GameArea.canvas.width){
   this.xAngle = -1 * this.xAngle;
  }
  if(this.y + this.radius > GameArea.canvas.height){
   this.yAngle = -1 * this.yAngle;; 
  }
  if(this.x - this.radius < 0){
   this.xAngle = -1 * this.xAngle;
  } 
  if(this.y - this.radius < 0){
   this.yAngle = -1 * this.yAngle;
  }
  this.update();
 }
}
function updateGameArea(){
Ball.updateGameComp();
Ball1.updateGameComp();
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset='urf-8'>
  <style>
   canvas{
    border: 0px solid black;
   }
   body{
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body onload='startGame()'>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <script src='Pong.js'></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read [this question and my answer to it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161164/javascrit-prototype-inheritance-and-html-canvas/42162355#42162355). The problem lies in your re-usage of the canvas' `context`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `CircComp` objects call `GameArea.clear()` in `updateGameComp`. You should only clear the canvas once, *before* drawing anything, probably in `updateGameArea`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me why is that?

Comment: `GameArea.clear()` blanks out the entire canvas. So right now in `updateGameArea` you: 1. Clear the previous image, 2. Draw a ball 3. Clear the image again (erasing the first ball), and 4. Draw the second ball.

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you!

Comment: No I'm pretty new in this community and it doesn't let me to do that :(